# What does the new "helpful flags" field in the profile page count?

Tags: support, flagging

Recently the [flag weight field was scrapped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119715) from the profile page, and replaced by a “helpful flags” field. I would like a clarification about how this new system works.

Here is my flagging history from my profile page*:

[image: flagging history]

**My questions:**

(a) My current “helpful flags” count is 20, and I presume that this is because 2 of my comment flags have been deemed helpful. Is this interpretation correct?

(b) Does this mean that flagging posts will not contribute to this count?

**Edit:** I removed the feature request from this post and am posting it as a separate post. Apologies for the inconvenience.

---

*This is private information, but I am posting it anyway in order to make the question concrete.

Comment: Off-topic: is there any trick to center the image?

Comment: Also, I am wondering whether this question is more suitable for meta.SO.

Comment: As a side note, I am not exactly sure how the system decides whether a comment flag is helpful (since the interfaces for dealing with comment flags and post flags are somewhat different). So I have no idea whether one should change one's habits in regards to comment flags based on a "low" comment flag helpfulness score....

Comment: @Willie: Oh, I did not know that the system decides this. I had assumed that the moderator who handles the flag deems it as helpful or not. [Hm, it turns out this question was not totally useless to me then. :-)]

Comment: flags on posts are decided by moderators. flags on comments are more tricky: we as moderators don't get to say outright whether the flag is helpful or not, so I don't know how they translate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself: my interpretation was **wrong**. In fact, the 20 corresponds to the sum of all the helpful flags:

> 17 helpful mod attention flags + 1 post marked offensive + 2 helpful comment flags = 20 helpful flags.

Of course, in retrospect, this is more natural than what I wrote in the post, but I am not sure why it didn't strike me until now.  Perhaps I was deceived by the round figure of 20 (which I assumed was related to the 2 comment flags).

I figured this out because today I had successfully flagged two more posts and my helpful flag count has increased to 22.